# ViewResolver not resolving to view name, but to request URL, Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, jsp

The viewresolver is resolving to request url rather than the view name returned, help me out here as I am new to Spring

The logs are showing :

```
MethodName : springController()

ClassName : ModelAndView: reference to view with name 'StartPage'; model is {message=Hey welcome to Spring 3.0!! }
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MethodName : springContoller

Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'home'
Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView: name 'home'; URL [/jsp/home.jsp]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'
Forwarding to resource [/jsp/home.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'home'
Successfully completed request
```

bean config:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
```

Controller :

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objmapper;

    @Autowired
    public SLogger tLogger;

    @RequestMapping("/home")
    public ModelAndView springContoller(){
        String message = "Hey welcome to Spring 3.0!! ";
        System.out.println("in controller");
        tLogger.writeToLog(HomeController.class.getName(), "springController()", Level.DEBUG);
        return new ModelAndView("StartPage","message",message);
    }
    }
```

Rather than resolving to /jsp/StartPage.jsp it is resolving to /jsp/home.jsp, Why?

spring-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan
        base-package="siso.springrolls.controller" />

    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper">
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="file:D:/galilio/siso.properties"></property>
    </bean>

   <bean id="sLogger"
            class="siso.springrolls.utilities.SLogger" factory-method="getLogger">
            <property name="iLogger" ref="iLogger"></property>
   </bean> 

    <bean id="iLogger" class="org.apache.log4j.Logger" factory-method="getLogger">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="ILogger"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="logAspect" class="siso.springrolls.utilities.LoggingAspect"></bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml :

```
 <servlet>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/home</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping> 
 <context-param>  
      <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
      <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>  
</context-param> 

<listener>  
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>  
</listener>
```

Comment: Let's see your other beans. Which is named `home`?

Comment: there is no such bean defined in my bean config file

Comment: added bean config file, **I tried changing UrlBasedViewResolver to InternalResourceViewResolver**

Comment: It might be component scanned. What other classes have you defined as components?

Comment: only the controller package, and for now it only contains HomeController.java, main controller class

Comment: Please post the controller too. I see no reason why you'd get this behavior with what you've shown. Please make sure you've included all relevant details. Are there any other `@Component` annotated types in `siso.springrolls.controller` or its sub-packages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58088/discussion-between-siso-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and the solution is very simple - instead of importing package

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
```

you have imported

```
import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is work-around,but it will work.
Do as following
In web.xml

```
 <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>
```

In your HomeController

```
//first landing controller
 //it will redirect to your home controller
 @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public ModelAndView home() {
    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/home")
 }

 @RequestMapping("/home")
 public ModelAndView springContoller(){
    String message = "Hey welcome to Spring 3.0!! ";
    System.out.println("in controller");
    tLogger.writeToLog(HomeController.class.getName(), "springController()",
    Level.DEBUG);
    return new ModelAndView("StartPage","message",message);
 }
```

Here if you add `url-pattern as /home` , that means servlet will map only /home directory.
So we changed to it `/`

Comment: Why would this change anything?

Comment: when I changed url-pattern in web.xml to /StartPage and in controller @RequestMapping("/StartPage"), it works fine, so why not with /home, as these two mappings relate to each other only, and independent of the view returned

Answer (score 0):

I encountered similar issues when I add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>`.  After removing it from my configuration file, everything is fine.